# Is the volatile keyword required for fields accessed via a ReentrantLock?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, volatile, reentrancy

My question refers to whether or not the use of a ReentrantLock guarantees visibility of a field in the same respect that the synchronized keyword provides.

For example, in the following class *A*, the field *sharedData* does not need to be declared volatile as the synchronized keyword is used.

```
class A 
{
  private double sharedData;

  public synchronized void method() 
  {
    double temp = sharedData;
    temp *= 2.5;
    sharedData = temp + 1;
  } 
}
```

For next example using a ReentrantLock however, is the volatile keyword on the field necessary?

```
class B 
{
  private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private volatile double sharedData;

  public void method() 
  {
    lock.lock();
    try
    {
      double temp = sharedData;
      temp *= 2.5;
      sharedData = temp + 1;
    }
    finally
    {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  } 
}
```

I know that using the volatile keyword anyway will only likely impose a miniscule performance hit, but I would still like to code correctly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's safe without volatility. `ReentrantLock` implements `Lock`, and the [docs for `Lock`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) include this:

> All `Lock` implementations must enforce
>   the same memory synchronization
>   semantics as provided by the built-in
>   monitor lock, as described in The Java
>   Language Specification, Third Edition
>   (17.4 Memory Model):
>
> - A successful `lock` operation has the
>     same memory synchronization effects as
>     a successful `Lock` action.
> - A successful
>     `unlock` operation has the same memory
>     synchronization effects as a
>     successful `Unlock` action.

Comment: Is this advice true with regards to `while (field)` due to field hoisting?

Comment: @Pod: Without more specific details of how the `while` loop interacts with the lock, it's impossible to say. You probably want to create a new question with a specific example.

Comment: If I want to read the latest value of `sharedData` in other threads without locking, should `sharedData` be declared volatile?

Comment: @Poison: It's more complex than that, and frankly I don't understand it well enough to be confident in giving guidance.