# Why Java EE singleton session bean's fields don't have to be volatile?

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, volatile

Here is singleton session bean example from Java EE tutorial:

```
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER) 
@Singleton
public class ExampleSingletonBean {

    private String state;

    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    public void setState(String newState) {
        state = newState;
    }
}
```

How it is possible that `private String state` field don't have to be volatile? How application server can guarantee that this reference never be cached thread-locally for different, simultaneous HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipsz/index.html), when you use a `CONTAINER`, a `Lock` is used.

Now the lock itself somehow emulates `volatile`, as can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570589/is-the-volatile-keyword-required-for-fields-accessed-via-a-reentrantlock):

> All `Lock` implementations must enforce
>   the same memory synchronization
>   semantics as provided by the built-in
>   monitor lock, as described in The Java
>   Language Specification, Third Edition
>   (17.4 Memory Model):
>
> - A successful `lock` operation has the
>     same memory synchronization effects as
>     a successful `Lock` action.
> - A successful
>     `unlock` operation has the same memory
>     synchronization effects as a
>     successful `Unlock` action.

In other words, the *implicit* lock is "volatile" (perhaps not necessarily by keyword, but by implementation).